# Makefile to move programs to specific directory

Tags: c++, bash, makefile, mv

I have a makefile that I personally didn't write, and I'm not very good at bash scripting and makefiles in general, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge beforehand;

AS the title states I simply want to move my executables when compiled to a ../bin/ folder. My attempt at this (shamelessy copied from another post here on SO) is given below (i.e. i tried making a phony install which should move the files, but alas it doesnt."

```
CXX = g++
CC  = g++


# Define preprocessor, compiler, and linker flags. Uncomment the # lines
# if you use clang++ and wish to use libc++ instead of libstd++.
CPPFLAGS  = -std=c++11 -I..
CXXFLAGS  = -g -O2 -Wall -W -pedantic-errors
CXXFLAGS += -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wold-style-cast 
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 
LDFLAGS   = -g -L..
MV = mv
PROG_PATH = ../bin/
#CPPFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++
#LDFLAGS +=  -stdlib=libc++

# Libraries
#LDLIBS = -lclientserver
# Targets
PROGS = myserver myclient libclientserver.a   
all: $(PROGS)
# Targets rely on implicit rules for compiling and linking
 # The dependency on libclientserver.a is not defined.
myserver: myserver.o messagehandler.o server.o connection.o database_memory.o database_file.o 
myclient: myclient.o connection.o server.o messagehandler.o
libclientserver.a: connection.o server.o
    ar rv libclientserver.a  connection.o server.o
    ranlib libclientserver.a

# Phony targets
.PHONY: all install clean

all: $(PROGS) install
install: $(MV) $(PROGS) $(PROG_PATH)




# Standard clean
clean:
rm -f *.o $(PROGS)

# Generate dependencies in *.d files
%.d: %.cc
    @set -e; rm -f $@; \
     $(CPP) -MM $(CPPFLAGS) $< > $@.$$$$; \
     sed 's,\($*\)\.o[ :]*,\1.o $@ : ,g' < $@.$$$$ > $@; \
     rm -f $@.$$$$

# Include the *.d files
 SRC = $(wildcard *.cc)
include $(SRC:.cc=.d)
```

So how would I best do this? The compiler says

```
 make: *** No rule to make target `mv', needed by `install'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A makefile rule consists of two parts, a declaration of the rule's dependencies and the commands to invoke.

The dependencies are listed on the first line of the rule after the colon and the commands to execute are listed on subsequent lines, all indented with tabs.

Your install rule needs to depend on the programs which you are moving and possibly the destination directory  (you may want a rule that creates the destination), but not the `mv` utility itself as you don't need to build that.

```
install: $(PROGS)
    mv $(PROGS) $(PROG_PATH)
```

Note that although I've used four spaces, the indentation needs to be a tab. As you don't (yet?) have a rule to make `PROG_PATH`, I've left it out of the dependency list.

Also note that with this rule, make will have to rebuild your programs if you invoke make twice as they will have moved. You way want to consider using `cp` or `install` instead of `mv`.

Comment: I thought i could specify PROG_PATH = ../bin/
as I did in the top part of the file.

Now, when I use cp $(PROGS) $(PROG_PATH) it says cp: target '../bin/' is not a directory. So I guess that solved the makefile problem, but how do I go about defining ../bin as a variable to enter into cp util?

Regards, and thanks for your time and answer

Comment: Also, regarding your point about rebuilding, if i do make all , that would build the programs yes? and install would move. Because that's part of the specification for this assignment, and so It's fine either way if i have to rebuild between calls. And lastly, why does cp $(PROGS) ../bin/ work but not mv ?

Comment: Your problem is that `../bin/` didn't exist (or possibly existed but wasn't a directory) when you invoked `make`. You don't currently have a rule to make it (something that does `mkdir ../bin` or equivalent) so you need to either add such a rule or make sure that it exists before running `make`.